# On two different definitions of the Lebesgue Inner Measure

Tags: measure-theory, definition

Here are two definitions for the Lebesgue inner measure (below $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ are the Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue outer measure respectively):

**Definition 1:** the ***Lebesgue inner measure*** $\mu_*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$\mu_*:A\mapsto \sup\left\{\mu(C) : \text{ $C$ is a closed, measurable subset of $A$} \right\}.$$

**Definition 2:** the ***Lebesgue inner measure*** $\mu_*:\left\{\text{bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$}\right\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$\mu_*:A\mapsto \mu(E)-\mu^*(E\setminus A)$$
for any elementary set $E$ containing $A$.

---

**Are the two definitions above equivalent (for bounded sets)?**

**Is any of the above functions superadditive?**